# How to configure traefik for dns over tls?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have a problem configuring my traefik + pihole setup. I want to configure dns over tls. Maybe someone can point me out in right directions?

In debug process, i found about tool `kdig`. I have tried it:

```
 kdig -d @myiphere +tls-ca +tls-host=mydnshere  example.com                                                                                  07:36:12
;; DEBUG: Querying for owner(example.com.), class(1), type(1), server(myiphere), port(853), protocol(TCP)
;; DEBUG: TLS, imported 127 system certificates
;; WARNING: TLS, handshake failed (A TLS fatal alert has been received.)
```

Okay, so maybe a certificate is wrong? It does not look like it:

```
openssl s_client -connect mydnshere:853                                                                                                                                                    
CONNECTED(00000003)
/***bunch of text here***/
SSL handshake has read 5070 bytes and written 382 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
/***bunch of text here***/
```

Can someone point me out in right direction or tell what i am missing?

I have to mention that `dig domain.com @myiphere` and `dig +tcp domain.com @myiphere` are working fine.

Here is my configs:

traefik:

```
version: "3.8"                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
services:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  reverse-proxy:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    image: traefik                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    restart: unless-stopped                                                                                                                                                                                        
    command:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - "--api=true"                                                                                                                                                                                               
      - "--providers.docker=true"                                                                                                                                                                                  
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"                                                                                                                                                                
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"                                                                                                                                                                            
      - "--entrypoints.dns.address=:53"                                                                                                                                                                            
      - "--entrypoints.dot.address=:853"                                                                                                                                                                           
      - "--entrypoints.dns-udp.address=:53/udp"                                                                                                                                                                    
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"                                                                                                                                                                     
      - "--entrypoints.vpn-udp.address=:51820/udp"                                                                                                                                                                 
      - "--entrypoints.syncthing-tcp.address=:20000"                                                                                                                                                               
      - "--entrypoints.syncthing-udp.address=:20000/udp"                                                                                                                                                           
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"                                                                                                                                              
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"                                                                                                                                              
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.email=wkill95@gmail.com"                                                                                                                                                  
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"                                                                                                                                           
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge=true"                                                                                                                                                       
      - "--certificatesresolvers.le.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"                                                                                                                                             
      - "--pilot.token=${TRAEFIK_PILOT_TOKEN:-}"                                                                                                                                                                   
      - "--serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true"                                                                                                                                                               
      - "--log.level=${TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL:-ERROR}"                                                                                                                                                                  
    ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      # TODO: found out how to show remote ip in pihole                                                                                                                                                            
      #- "53:53"                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      #- "53:53/udp"                                                                                                                                                                                               
      - "853:853"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      # The HTTP port                                                                                                                                                                                              
      - "80:80"                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      - "443:443"                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      # VPN                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      - "51820:51820/udp"                                                                                                                                                                                          
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)                                                                                                                                                                
      #- "8080:8080"       
      # Syncthing
      - "22000:22000"
      - "22000:22000/udp"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - traefik_certs:/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-data.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_API_DOMAIN?No traefik api domain set}`) && ( Path(`/api/version`) || PathPrefix(`/api/http/`) || PathPrefix(`/api/tcp/`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-data.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-data.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-data.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api-data.tls.certresolver=${TRAEFIK_API_CERTRESOLVER?No traefik api certificate resolver}"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`${TRAEFIK_API_DOMAIN?No traefik api domain set}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=${TRAEFIK_API_CERTRESOLVER?No traefik api certificate resolver}"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=authelia@docker"

      - "flame.type=application"
      - "flame.name=Traefik"
      - "flame.url=https://${TRAEFIK_API_DOMAIN}"
      - "flame.icon=router-network"

volumes:
  traefik_certs:

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    name: reverse-proxy
```

pihole:

```
version: '3.8'                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
services:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  pihole:                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    image: pihole/pihole                                                                                                                                                                                           
    restart: unless-stopped                                                                                                                                                                                        
    env_file: pihole.environment                                                                                                                                                                                   
    cap_add:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - CAP_NET_ADMIN                                                                                                                                                                                              
    networks:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      - reverse-proxy                                                                                                                                                                                              
    dns:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      - 127.0.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      - 1.1.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ports:                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      - 53:53/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      - 53:53/udp                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      - 'pihole_configs:/etc/pihole/'                                                                                                                                                                              
    labels:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      - "traefik.enable=true"                                                                                                                                                                                      
      - "traefik.docker.network=reverse-proxy"                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-api.rule=Host(`${PIHOLE_DOMAIN:?No pihole domain set}`) && Path(`/admin/api.php`)"                                                                                            
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-api.tls=true"                                                                                                                                                                 
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-api.tls.certresolver=${PIHOLE_CERTRESOLVER?No pihole certificate resolver}"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-api.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-api.service=pihole"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole-api.loadBalancer.server.port=80"

      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.rule=Host(`${PIHOLE_DOMAIN:?No pihole domain set}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.tls.certresolver=${PIHOLE_CERTRESOLVER?No pihole certificate resolver}"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.service=pihole" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole.middlewares=authelia@docker"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole.loadBalancer.server.port=80"
      - "flame.type=application"
      - "flame.name=DNS"
      - "flame.url=https://${PIHOLE_DOMAIN}/admin"
      - "flame.icon=pi-hole"

      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dnsovertls.rule=HostSNI(`mydnshere`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dnsovertls.entrypoints=dot"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dnsovertls.tls.certresolver=le"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dnsovertls.service=pihole"

      # Normal DNS coming in on 53 TCP, no TLS
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dns.rule=HostSNI(`*`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dns.entrypoints=dns"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.dns.service=pihole"

      # recieves traffic from both the TLS and non-TLS traefik routers
      - "traefik.tcp.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=53"

      # Normal DNS coming in on 53 UDP
      - "traefik.udp.routers.udpdns.entrypoints=dns-udp"
      - "traefik.udp.routers.udpdns.service=pihole"
      - "traefik.udp.services.pihole.loadbalancer.server.port=53"
volumes:
  pihole_configs:

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external: true
```

Comment: Is this even right place to ask such questions?

Comment: test 1 if your pi-hole is working as expected using your browser or some other tool. 2 if traeffic is configured to use pi-hole correctly. Use `tcpdump` and relevant log files and update your question with the results

Comment: test 1 already done with `dig +tcp domain.com @myiphere`. test 2 already done with `openssl s_client -connect mydnshere:853`. i am 100% sure that my request reaches traefik, but maybe i want to check if i correctly use traefik configuration to forward tcp data to pihole. if you help with that, that will be cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem is that Traefik blocks the `dot` ALPN extension per default.

`docker compose logs` after kdig request showed:

```
tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([dot])
```

You can test this with openssl, too:

```
$ openssl s_client -alpn dot -connect mydnshere:853   
...
No ALPN negotiated
```

You can configure ALPN extensions for traefik with Docker as follows.

Additions to compose.yaml (rename service / router names accordingly):

```yaml
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.9"

    command: 
      # Provider Config
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/config.toml"

    volumes:
      - ./config.toml:/etc/traefik/config.toml

  blocky:
    image: spx01/blocky

    labels:
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.blocky-dns.rule=HostSNI(`my.fqn.com`)"
      - "traefik.tcp.routers.blocky-dns.tls.options=dot@file"
```

Add config.toml

```ini
[tls.options]
  [tls.options.dot]
    alpnProtocols = ["dot"]
```

Here is some background about ALPN dot: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/bind9/-/issues/2794

**Update** Removed the ALPN filter in the tcp router configuration as some clients do not advertise dot in ALPN (for example Android).

Comment: could you provide full working config? i dont see 853 port exposed or pihole in this configuration

Answer (score 1):

As @schlamar pointed in right direction, i will post exact steps for others.

In pihole container you just add this to labels section:

```
  - "traefik.tcp.routers.pihole-dot.tls=true"
  - "traefik.tcp.routers.pihole-dot.tls.certresolver=${PIHOLE_CERTRESOLVER?No pihole certificate resolver}"
  - "traefik.tcp.routers.pihole-dot.rule=HostSNI(`${PIHOLE_DOMAIN}`)"
  - "traefik.tcp.routers.pihole-dot.service=pihole-dns"
  - "traefik.tcp.services.pihole-dns.loadBalancer.server.port=53"
```

And in traefik container in labels section:

```
- "traefik.tls.option.default.alpnProtocols=http/1.1,h2,dot"
```

And everything working like a charm, you can now connect with your stuff (i am using it with my android phone)

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to understand what you are attempting to do here. Do you want to use Traefik as a proxy for Pihole DNS resolution attempts? I don't think that works out well, because you are using Traefik as a *reverse* proxy for your services.

Traefik handles incoming connections from the outside and sends back the corresponding answers. In case Pihole on its own decides to do a lookup it never goes through Traefik, as far as I know. **You got to configure a separate service for secured lookups**, like stubby or cloudflared. I recommend cloudflared (it does encrypted lookups via DoH), as there is an official [guide in their documentation](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns/cloudflared/).

Apart from that, the DNS field inside the docker compose file is for the docker container environment. But that's not where you configure the DNS address for Pihole lookups, you have to do that inside the Pihole application settings.

Comment: I want DNS over TLS. I am trying to replicate what i found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pihole/comments/fy8zmu/pihole_traefik_dnsovertls/)

Comment: Basically, i want my server get non error responce for command `kdig -d @myiphere +tls-ca +tls-host=mydnshere  example.com`

Comment: You can use Traefik as a TCP TLS Reverse Proxy to proxy to a non TLS TCP/IP port in a container. So his question is valid while your answer is definitely not helpful.